# Oracle dbms_job with invalid owner

Tags: oracle, jobs

Ok, database at a clients site that has dbms_job entries where the schema_user is invalid.  (It appears to be the effect of bringing over a schema from another machine using exp/imp.)

I would like to get rid of these jobs, but standard operating procedure says that you must connect as the owner of the jobs to dbms_job.remove() it.

I thought a workaround might be, to create the user in this instance, and then use it to remove the job.

Thoughts?

Edit:
Or even alternatively making direct edits to the sys.job$ table instead of going through the dbms_job interface?

Comment: What do you mean the "owner is invalid"? Can you make the owner valid, log in as that user, and remove the jobs? BTW I would recommend strongly against manipulating the Oracle internal tables.

Comment: Hi - I mean when I "select job,schema_user,what from dba_jobs" the value of schema_user is a non-existent user.  I'm sorry, I should have said "invalid schema_user" - editing original to reflect.

I'm also strongly opposed to messing with sys.job$, but I'm not sure I see an alternative - hence the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a package owned by SYS called DBMS_IJOB.  This offers pretty much the same functionality as DBMS_JOB but it allows us to manipulate jobs owned by other users.

If your rogue job is number 23 then this command should kill it:

```
SQL>  exec dbms_ijob.remove(23)
```

By default privileges on this package are not granted to other users, so you need to connect as SYS in order to execute it.   And remember to commit the change!